# How to add a date as the last column of a CSV file in Unix?

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have to add a date value as the last column of a CSV file in Unix.
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to append them to the last column, or do you want to add them as new columns at the end of each line? What dates do you want to add? Do you want multiple dates on each line or just a single date per line?

Comment: @Kusalananda new columns at the end of each line.. because thats what a column is. Otherwise it'd be a row.

Comment: @jdwolf No. There's a difference between changing `1,2,3` into `1,2,3-20180529` ("adding a date to the last column") and changing it into `1,2,3,20180529` ("adding a new column with a date").  I asked since the interpretation of "adding dates _in_ the last column" is clearly ambiguous.  Also "adding dates" could mean adding multiple dates to each record. It's unclear what is meant, and _what_ dates should be added (today's date, or depending on some files' timestamp, or depending on some other data in the file, or incrementing by one day throughout the file starting at some particular date).

Comment: @Kusalananda Agreed on all your points pretty much. I just like how you've worded it now is much clearly on what the OP needs to specify~ ty.

Comment: @aakansha please do [edit] and update your question to clarify what exactly you want your file be by providing a fragmented input/output samples.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `sed`:

```
sed "s/$/,$(date)/" infile.csv
```

With formatting:

```
sed "s/$/,$(date +'%F %T')/" infile
```

- the `$` in `s/$/.../` is pointing anchor to the end of line.
- we used double-quotes to expand the [command-substitution `$(...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) output.
- this adds *date* as a new column. remove comma `,` before `,$(...)` to append to the last column.
- use `-i` option of *sed* to in-place change in file itself or take a backup in addition:

  ```
  sed -i.bak "s/$/,$(date +'%F %T')/" infile
  ```

see for more formatting options in [**`man date`**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) under *"FORMAT controls"* section.